# Fazer CheckBox em C#

Tags: c#

Como inserir CheckBox no Form, a partir de uma base de dados. Onde o campo da tabela, será o Text do CheckBox?

Exemplo:

```
Tabela -- 
0|Versao
1|2.9.15
2|2.9.16
```

colocar 2 CheckBox para o usuário escolher a versão suportada.

Comment: Olá Ana, tudo bem? Então, se entendi direito você quer somente que o texto do check box fosse **2.9.15** ou **2.9.16**, é isso? Não consegui compreender bem sua pergunta. É possível que você seja sinalizada por isso.

Comment: Olá :) 
Sim exatamente, queria que o texto que aparecesse no "text da checkbox", fosse mandado pela base de dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que você tenha os valores que precisa em um DataTable:

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int h = 0;
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.Text = r["nome_do_campo"].ToString();
                cb.Checked = false;
                cb.Parent = this;
                cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, h);
                h += cb.Height;
                cb.Show();
            }
```

Implementando o código para utilizar o evento CheckedChanged:

```
 private void MontarCheckBox(DataTable dt)
    {
        int h = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            cb.Text = row["Version"].ToString();
            cb.Name = row["Version"].ToString();
            cb.Checked = false;
            cb.Parent = this; 
            cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, h); 
            h += cb.Height;
            cb.CheckedChanged += cb_CheckedChanged;
            cb.Show();
        }
    }

    void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //sender é o objeto CheckBox onde o evento ocorreu
        CheckBox cb = ((CheckBox)sender);
        if (cb.Checked)
        {
            string versao = cb.Name;
            //Faz o processamento que deseja
        }

    }
```

Comment: Muito Obrigada, resultou :)

Comment: por nada, =] Disponha.

Comment: Outra dúvida. 
Queria agora com o código anterior executado, imaginando que tenho 2 checkbox selecionados. Agora quero que quando estes dois tivessem selecionados, gravar o valor desses chechbox numa variavel, para depois poder fazer a comparação desses com outros valores.

Comment: nesse caso, defina um nome ou Tag para o checkbox

Comment: cb.Name = r["coluna_nome"].ToString();

Comment: aí você pode em algum evento, disparar a gravação dos dados, seja botão, load, qualquer coisa.

Comment: para o evento de Checagem do checkbox, utilize: cb.CheckedChanged += cb_CheckedChanged;

Comment: void cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //implementacao do evento
        }

Comment: Vou colocar aqui como fiz, porque não está a dar certo

Comment: `int h = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.Text = row["Version"].ToString();
                cb.Name = row["Version"].ToString();
                cb.Checked = false;
                cb.Parent = this;
                cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, h);
                h += cb.Height;
                cb.CheckedChanged += Cb_CheckedChanged;
                cb.Show();
            }´

Comment: private void Cb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            if(cb.Checked)
            {
                Start();
            }
        }

Comment: Mas está a dar erro :cb.CheckedChanged += Cb_CheckedChanged;

Comment: é que eu vou precisar do nome das checkbox selecionadas para fazer um update depois

Comment: momento, vou atualizar a resposta

Comment: pronto, atualizei a resposta